# AJAX page is not loading after giving <base href="/"> on page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

In my website, I edited the whole **htaccess for making user-friendly url**. But after giving the .htaccess file, style for the site is not taking. So I modified all my link of the site like, **http://www.sitename/foldername/filename**.

my ajax code is:

```
if(this.id=="cl_onmem"){
            var ccat2='<?php echo $cc2; ?>';
                $(".right_displayBx").html( ajax_csrh("cfilter1.php","omid=live&ccat2="+ccat2); 
            }
```

my htaccess code is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /Classifieds/

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\s [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\?id=([^&\s]+)\&title=([^&\s]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%3? [R,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
    RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2&title=$3[QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
    RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

But after that, the **ajax pages and other pages are repeating** on the page and **showing multiple pages on a single window**..

So I gave  on the top of the page...

But after that **ajax pages on my site are not working..it directly redirecting to the Index...**

Anybody Please help me..

**Thanks in advance...**

Comment: You really need to include your code, we can't do nuttin' without it.

Comment: 'Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews'
   ' RewriteEngine On'
 RewriteBase /foldername/

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\s [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\?id=([^&\s]+)\&title=([^&\s]+) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%3? [R,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
    RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2&title=$3[QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
    RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

Comment: Edit your question and paste the code in there.

Comment: @epodax..please check it now..

Comment: i have only the problem with ajax page...all others are working..

Comment: Include your ajax code.

Comment: if(this.id=="cl_onmem"){
            var ccat2='<?php echo $cc2; ?>';
                $(".right_displayBx").html( ajax_csrh("cfilter1.php","omid=live&ccat2="+ccat2); 
            }

Comment: this is my ajax code....@epodax @amarjeet kumar